# Setting up a C++ project using ANGLE and GLFW on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl-es, glfw, google-angle

I'm trying to set up a basic OpenGL ES 2.0 application on Windows using ANGLE. I've installed GLFW via vcpkg, together with ANGLE (either by patching vcpkg with [#7923](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/7923) and [#8785](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/8785), or building locally) and can build the application. I've also got d3dcompiler_47.dll in the output directory. Unfortunately at runtime it looks like none of the OpenGL ES calls are succeeding.

I'm initialising GLFW as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES2
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not init GLFW\n";
        return 1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    auto window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test GLES", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create window\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // rest of code goes here
```

After the call to `glfwMakeContextCurrent` I expect the OpenGL ES context to be available. However:

- Calls to `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` and `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` all return a null pointer.
- Calls to `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)` returns 0 (i.e. failure), but `glGetError()` gives `GL_NO_ERROR`.

The same code is working correctly on Linux on the same machine, so I assume I need to do something else to get things to work on Windows.

My searches have come up with little useful information for doing this (but it did suggest to do the `glGetString` checks). I assume that what I'm missing is sufficiently obvious that no-one's bothered to put it in the explanations, so I'm going to feel quite silly when I know what's going wrong.

Any suggestions for what I'm missing here?

Comment: Does the Windows graphics driver support OpenGL ES ?

Comment: Does your graphic card/driver support OpenGL ES?

Comment: As I understand it, ANGLE on Windows should translate OpenGL ES into DirectX calls (dxdiag reports DirectX 12). Nevertheless the card definitely supports GLES from Linux.

Comment: Your graphic card could support OpenGL ES on Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: @JoseMaria possibly, but that is one of the cases that's supposed to be addressed by ANGLE. I'm definitely able to run Qt applications, which uses OpenGL ES via ANGLE...

Comment: I mean you have forgotten this: glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_CREATION_API, GLFW_EGL_CONTEXT_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is specified, you should ask for an OpenGL ES context:

glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_CREATION_API, GLFW_EGL_CONTEXT_API) ;

https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#GLFW_CONTEXT_CREATION_API_hint

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It turns out that *none* of the sources I was using mentioned that, possibly some changes to the APIs over the several years since they were written.